# CORs error when accessing Square V2 API

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, square

I'm making a client-side request out to V2 of the Square API using [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) and [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). My Vue component is as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    mounted() {
        var instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/',
            timeout: 1000,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'Accepts': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        instance.get('catalog/list')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }) ;
    }
}
```

However, when I make that call, I receive the following error:

```
Failed to load https://connect.squareup.com/v2/catalog/list: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://local-env.dev' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

That error suggests that there is some configuration that has to happen on the Square side, but I saw no opportunity to whitelist domains, etc.

Has anyone come across this error before, regardless of service, and if so, how did you resolve?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the Square API supports being called from a browser.  I used Postman to do an OPTIONS request on `https://connect.squareup.com/v2/catalog/list` and the response was a `NOT_FOUND`.  The OPTIONS request is needed for proper [CORS support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Plus, if you did this, I would think your auth token would need to be sent to the client -- thus exposing it to everyone.  It looks like the Square API is only designed to be called from a server.  But that is just based on me skimming the docs a bit.  I have no experience using their API.

Comment: Correct, client side calling would expose your access token, giving anyone access to your Square account.

Comment: Technically if you only give read-only scope to your access token then this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

When doing OAuth authorization request you are not supposed to do it from your application. Create and URL with the parameters and open it in a new browser window or tab, Something like:

```
 const grants='MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ CUSTOMERS_READ CUSTOMERS_WRITE PAYMENTS_READ PAYMENTS_WRITE PAYMENTS_WRITE_ADDITIONAL_RECIPIENTS PAYMENTS_WRITE_IN_PERSON';
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('scope', grants)
        .set('client_id', <YourSquareApplicationId>)
        .set('state', '1878789');
    const requestUrl = `${<squareUrl>}/oauth2/authorize?${params.toString()}`;
    window.open(requestUrl, "_blank");
```

That new window is supposed to ask the end user to login to his account and accept or deny the request.